# R GET JSON from list of urls and assign names

Tags: r, json, function, url, get

I am trying to create a function to GET JSON data from a list of URLs and assign names accordingly.

I have dataset for many metrics. The head looks like:

| Metric | Url |
| --- | --- |
| Local | https://www.ons.gov.uk/economy/grossdomesticproductgdp/timeseries/njiq/ukea/data |
| Value | https://www.ons.gov.uk/economy/grossvalueaddedgva/timeseries/abml/pn2/data |

I can extract one by one with:

```
Local <- GET("https://www.ons.gov.uk/economy/grossdomesticproductgdp/timeseries/abmi/pn2/data") %>%
  content(as = "text") %>%  
  fromJSON()
```

But I cannot figure out how to create a function that can be applied to the datasets, and that get the JSON and assign the name accordingly without having to run one by one for each row. Thank you.

Comment: `lapply(dataset$Url, function(i) fromJSON(content(GET(i), as = 'text')))` should put them all in a list for you

Comment: Then I think I can assign names with `names(lst) <- dataset$Metric`. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`lapply(dataset$Url, function(i) fromJSON(content(GET(i), as = 'text')))`
@Allan Cameron
Thank you